# How to copy target files using symlinks and a list of file names

Tags: files, symlink, cp

I would like to copy many files. I have their location as a set of symbolic links whose names are stored as lines in a txt file. So I am using cp and need to combine the readlink and cat/pipe functions. I haven't seen other questions deal with this combination.

The command:

`cp $(readlink < /path/list.txt) -t /path/targetdir`

A simpler example works where the symlink names are used explicitly in the argument of the readlink (but I have too many file names to do this manually), e.g.:

`cp $(readlink symlink1 symlink2) -t /path/targetdir`

The issue is in how I am combining the 'readlink' and the pipe, but I can't figure out what.

EDIT:
here's an example of what's in the first lines of the list.txt file:

`symlink_13243`

`symlink_39184`

`symlink_83204`

each row is a unique symlink name.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a few of your file entries please. In your question, not here as a comment

Comment: Use `xargs` when an argument list is too long. What's wrong with the first command?

Comment: The first command gives two errors: ```readlink: missing operand``` and ```cp: missing operand```

Comment: no, neither spaces nor hyphens. They are fasta file names: e.g.   ```file.1234.fasta```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `xargs` and `readlink`:

```
</path/list.txt xargs -d'\n' readlink -z | xargs -0 cp -t /path/targetdir
```

With one symbolic link per line in `list.txt`, choose newline (`\n`) as delimiter for the first `xargs` and pipe `readlink`'s output to another `xargs`, this time using a null character to terminate the paths (`-z` and `-0`).

Comment: thanks! but it only copies the last file of the list. Anything I should add or try?

Answer (score 0):

It worked by using a loop and `cp -L` instead of `readlink`.
I ran the following command in the folder that contained the symlinks:

```
for item in $(cat /path/dir/list.txt); do cp -L $item /path/targetdir; done
```

also I had encoding issues with the txt file (related to building it in R but on a Windows machine).